# Computer can't be pinged, Tracert'd, Wont allow RDP, or PSSessoin. What am I missing?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, powershell, printer, ping

- Device is running Windows 7 and has all updates
- Confirmed network connectivity and can ping and tracert to whomever it wants even though no device can ping/tracert to it.
- Remote protocol is enabled (Same as others that I can get into)
- The group policy settings in WinRM is correctly configured, and PSRemoting is enabled. (Same as others that I can start a session with)
- Freshly installed printer it's housing is listed on active directory but can't be connected to.

Is there something I'm overlooking? I feel like the answers either going to be right under my nose or something wildly obscure.

Comment: Firewall? Either the Windows Firewall on the device itself, or a firewall between it and other machines.

Comment: Unfortunately no the firewall settings allow all the above. I really cant drill down to any reason why this machine is being so stubborn

Comment: My next step would be to capture packets (https://www.wireshark.org/) on the offending machine and see if the pings are either A) getting to it, and not being returned; or B) not getting to it. That could narrow it down.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?